# Correct @font-face paths with webpack for a package included with SASS?

Tags: npm, sass, webpack

I have a webpack project:

```
main.js
project.scss
```

In my project root I also have a custom NPM package called my-package. Im this are fonts and a SASS file which uses them:

```
my-package/fonts/font.woff
my-package/fonts/font.woff2
my-package/fonts.scss
```

In fonts.scss:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: $myfont;
  src:
  url('./fonts/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('./fonts/font.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Ive tried importing fonts.scss into project.scss:

In project.scss

```
@include "./my-package/fonts.scss";
```

However the path to the fonts are wrong. As its just a SASS include the paths are taken relative to project.scss, so it would need to be this to work:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: $myfont;
  src:
  url('./my-package/fonts/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('./my-package/fonts/font.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Can I make webpack import the SASS file so thats its variables etc are available, but also have it correct the paths to the font files? The custom module is my own so I can change the code for it but I don't want to change it to something nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What you could do is create a *your-font.scss* file to accompany your font and import the *your-font.scss* file once in a base file in your app and not import it in another .scss  again. That way your URL will be correct.